# How do you use Jenkins libraryResource to read file from resources?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm unable to use `libraryResource` to load a resource using Jenkins.
I've found plenty of example of people using `libraryResource` to load resources but no one that has the specific errors i'm getting so i assume that i'm missing something but i've no idea what that might be.

I'm trying to load a python script that will be reused by almost all jobs.
I've placed a simple test script in `resouces/org/foo/test.py` which as far as i understand i should be able to read using:

```
libraryResource('org/foo/test.py')
```

But i get the error:

> hudson.AbortException: No such library resource org/foo/test.py could be found.

I use a pipeline script that is loaded from SCM that is configured in the projects configuration in jenkins. This is the structure of the git repository from which the pipeline script is loaded.

```
-src
  -org
    -shared
      +Utilities.groovy
-jobs
  -nighly
    +nightly.groovy
-resources
  -org
   -foo
    +test.py
```

Loading the `Utitilies.groovy` using shared library at the root of nightly.groovy

```groovy
@Library('shared-utilities')
import org.shared.Utilities
```

What I've tried:

- Running `libraryResource` outside of stages, in stages and on nodes
- Checking out `scm` before running `libraryResource`
- Different paths `foo/test.py`, `resources/org/foo/test.py`

Based on the output from checkout scm the latest commit containing `resources/org/foo/test.py` is being fetched and it's there on the job root on the agent.

I'm out of ideas and I appreciate any help/suggestion that you have. I really would like to avoid having to commit this script to all projects that use it since its only used by Jenkins.

Comment: Are you running on a single node? Or a master-slave configuration?  If so, you may find that the shared libraries are being checked out on to the master, but the stage that calls `libraryResource` is running on a different node.  I'm not sure if `libraryResource` works that way, but I'm currently dealing with the same issue.

Comment: I'm running a master-slave configuration. I was under the impression that the issue you're describing is exactly what libraryResources is meant to fix i.e acting as a shared storage for resources across nodes. But it was a while since i've worked with this so i'm not 100% sure.

And as i mentioned i've tried "Running libraryResource outside of stages, in stages and on nodes" so i don't think that is the issue.

Comment: I suspect so. In the end, I had been thwarted by an incorrect file path. At least the error makes sense in my case!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you're missing is the context/scenario under which usage of [`libraryResource`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps-global-lib/#libraryresource-load-a-resource-file-from-a-shared-library) API becomes applicabLe.

> **`libraryResource`: Load a resource file from a shared library**
>   Reads a resource from a shared library and returns its content as a plain
>   string.

So if you had provisioned a shared library, then you may use [`libraryResource`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps-global-lib/#libraryresource-load-a-resource-file-from-a-shared-library) ***inside*** your shared library to read a resource in located in `resource` directory of the ***same*** shared library.

Hope that clears things up better.

Comment: How can we use libraryResource to acess resource directory from a different shared library? I have two shared libraries setup in Jenkins and I want to access the resource/ directory of one from the other. Both have been setup in Jenkins, I have added @Library(['lib1','lib2']) but it doesn't work

Comment: Use a `step` provided in library **A** to indirectly fetch the desired resource into your _pipeline_, and in your _pipeline_ use the fetched resource as an argument to call a `step` in library **B**.

Comment: can you fetch an entire folder with libraryResource?

Comment: The documentation reads _load a resource **file**..._. So, you would have to load the folder files one after the other.

Comment: that stinks! is that really the only way? Is there a way to iterate over all files in a subfolder in the "resources" dir? Im kind of shocked, that seriously limits its use cases

Comment: None that I know of, unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

I've still not been able to get libraryResource to work i'm assuming that i'm missing something in how jenkins, the jobs, shared resources are setup but i can't find it.

In the meantime i'm using this so that i can move forward.

```
public static String loadJenkinsResource(String pathToResource) {
    return getResourceFromJenkinsCSM(pathToResource)
}

private static String getResourceFromJenkinsCSM(String pathToResource) {
    mainScript.checkout mainScript.scm
    return "resources/${pathToResource}"
}

private static String getResourceFromLibrary(String pathToResource) {
    def resourceContent = mainScript.libraryResource(pathToResource)
    def outputFile = getFileNameFromPath(pathToResource)
    mainScript.writeFile file: outputFile, text: resourceContent
    mainScript.sh "chmod +x ${outputFile}"
    return outputFile
}
```

getResourcesFromLibrary is untested